# How to programmatically create UIlabel inside a custom uiView swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uilabel

how can i create 5 custom uilabel inside a custom `UIView`. Which will align one after the other. i have tried to create the `UILabel` inside the custom `UIView`. but it does not go inside the custom `UIView`.

//updated with the loop

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var getMainViewX = mainView.frame.origin.x
    let getMainViewY = mainView.frame.origin.y

    for var i = 0; i < 5; i++
    {

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(getMainViewX, getMainViewY, 200, 21))
        //label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.text = "I'am a test label"
        self.mainView.addSubview(label)
        getMainViewX+=20
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

[image: the light gray box in the middle is the uiview]

Comment: Run a loop of 5 doing the same thing. Increment your getMainViewY by um lets say 20 with each loop counter.

Comment: how can i get the uilabel aligned inside the custom uiview

Comment: Share the code of how you are adding your custom View to Viewcontroller's view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using iOS 9, the recently added [Stack View](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIStackView) has been created for exactly this purpose.

1. Use a UIStackView for your `mainView` instead of a default view
2. You can set the alignment properties of the stack view in Interface Builder
3. Create the labels in your loop, then add them to the stack view using the `addArrangedSubview` method of the stack view.

The stack view will take care of the alignment, spacing and layout of it's subviews for you.

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear what you mean by "align". 
Assuming you want them one stacked one below another, I have made minor adjustments to your code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let getMainViewX = mainView.frame.origin.x
    //let getMainViewY = mainView.frame.origin.y

    for var i = 0; i < 5; i++
    {
        //let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(getMainViewX, getMainViewY, 200, 21))
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(getMainViewX, CGFloat(i) * 21, 200, 21))
        //label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.text = "I'am a test label"
        self.mainView.addSubview(label)
        //getMainViewX+=20
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

[Hopefully this is how you are looking to align the labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5LUM.png)